# Has anyone applied Machine Learning methods to Geochemical Data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am looking to do a project on geochemical data , on which I will apply Machine Learning Technqiues to hopefully achieve good results.

I was wondering whether anyone has done anything like this and could guide me to some resources or research papers?

Comment: Have you considered doing a [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=geochemical+machine+learning&t=canonical&ia=web)? There are peer reviewed papers ([1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.gexplo.2018.01.019), [2](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.gexplo.2018.01.002)) that seem to be broadly on the topic.